# C++ NCurses how to get current cursor position?

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses, cursor-position

How do I get the current position of the cursor in terminal with NCurses using C++?  I searched around a bit and saw "getxy(int x, int y)".  I tried that and got the error "'getxy' was not declared in this scope".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have forgotten some `#include <ncurses.h>` and the macro is spelled [getyx](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getyx)

Don't forget to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and to link with `-lncurses`

Answer (score 6):

```
getyx(WINDOW *win,int y,int x);
```

not getxy().

Answer (score 0):

This function only allow you to set the cursor to position, you should look at the getmouse function to get the mouse event.